# android how to download PDF fie in web view

Tags: android, android-webview

[image]

i have to use webview to show asp.net rdlc report using http url.

now i can download PDF file in web view show option in bellow image

Answer (score 0):

You should create WebViewClient and set it to your webview.

every time you click a link WebViewClient's shouldOverrideUrlLoading method will be called.

You can get the PDF url, now call async task and download the file in device.

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, String url) {
        if (url.endsWith(".pdf")) {
          // call Asynctask and download pdf file
          return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for ans. i implement this code but not download my pdf file

Comment: Did you get .pdf url in shouldOverrideUrlLoading?

Comment: i get url but not with .pdf

Comment: which url you get?

Comment: mybaseurl+Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?Culture=1033&CultureOverrides=True&UICulture=1033&UICultureOverrides=True&ReportStack=1&ControlID=c1cc316ae2d941aa90243845effb75ff&Mode=true&OpType=Export&FileName=Admin&ContentDisposition=OnlyHtmlInline&Format=PDF

Comment: You need to ask the web developer that he needs to add another parameter that shows the pdf url after that you can get the pdf url from the URL string and download. I have the same issue in one of my app.